# How to simplify Log[ Exp[x] *y ]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can the following expression be simplified:

```
Log[
  Sqrt[ (m/(2*Pi*k*T)^3) *4*Pi*v^2 ] * Exp[ -(m*v^2 / (2*k*T)) ]
]
```

I would like to get the result:

```
Log[ Sqrt[ (m/(2*Pi*k*T)^3) *4*Pi*v^2 ] ]  - (m*v^2 / (2*k*T))
```

Comment: `expr /. Log[a_ E^b_] :> b + Log[a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all variables are positive:

```
FullSimplify[Log[Sqrt[(m/(2*Pi*k*T)^3)*4*Pi*v^2]*Exp[-(m*v^2/(2*k*T))]],{T>0,k>0,m>0,v>0}]

1/2 (-((m v^2)/(k T))+Log[(m v^2)/(2 k^3 \[Pi]^2 T^3)])
```

Is this better? Yours to decide.

***EDIT:***

Okay since you explained it in detail you just want to use the rule

$$\log\left(\exp \left(x\right)\cdot y\right)=x+\log\left(y\right)$$

So we implement this single rule as PatternMatching:

```
Log[Sqrt[(m/(2*Pi*k*T)^3)*4*Pi*v^2]*Exp[-(m*v^2/(2*k*T))]]/.Log[Exp[a_]*b_]:>a+Log[b]

-((m v^2)/(2 k T)) + Log[Sqrt[(m v^2)/(k^3 T^3)]/(Sqrt[2] \\[Pi])]
```

Comment: Nearly what I wanted: Since `Log[Exp[x] * y] = x + Log[y]`, it would be nice keep the expression in `x` and `y` as they are originally.

Comment: Look into the newest edit.

Comment: This is great ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `PowerExpand` is what you're looking for. Not simpler, but expanded.

Comment: This is interesting but expanding everything ...